# Ms access Speed issue with vista office 07

Tags: windows-vista, performance, microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-access

Greeting,

I lately upgraded my MS Office from 03 to office 07, Using windows Vista.

I am using an access based program for my business and it was very smooth and fast, but since the upgrade everything got screwed up , the program can take a full minute to load , it got extremely slow.

All office programs are working fine and fast no issues but only this access program somehow clashes with this combination from 07 and vista, I tried to call the company but they are blaming the compute, But again it was working fine and just the office upgrade killed it.

Any advice idea what this could be??

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue and well talked about in many forums when [searched on the Internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=access+database+very+slow+after+upgrade+to+2007).

Here are a couple things you can try to improve the performance.

1. Convert the database to the 2007 format
2. Compact and repair the database
3. There were a number of updates and hot fixes to deal with issues in Access 2007. Read [Converting to Access 2007 or 2010](http://allenbrowne.com/Access2007.html) by MVP Allen Browne.